# Why will Fish not recognize a program it can find in its path?

Tags: path, fish

In a nutshell:

```
> which gitmux && ls -al (which gitmux) && gitmux
/home/psychoslave/bin/gitmux
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 psychoslave psychoslave 2752512  6 janv. 19:11 /home/psychoslave/bin/gitmux*
fish: gitmux: command not found...
> echo $PATH
/home/psychoslave/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/bin ~/bin […]
```

So, what's going on here? Fish clearly know where to find the program, but will pretend it doesn't?

Comment: That's not *fish* finding the program, that's `which`, an external program. Use `type gitmux`, which will check external commands, functions and builtins.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed by @faho, `which` doesn't use Fish’s PATH.

Moreover it seems that Fish won't expand `~/bin` for you, at least as I was setting it. Using a fully qualified path made the trick.

Comment: See https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/2310 for discussion on this